# Modify SQL query to also get number of times ordered

Tags: mysql, sql, reports, query

I am using the following SQL query from http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/calculating-lifetime-value-of-a-customer-in-magento/ to pull the amount of money each customer has spent with us.  I would also like to see the number of orders that were placed and even the date of first order if that's possible.  How can I modify the SQL query to get this?

`SELECT DISTINCT customer_email, customer_firstname, customer_lastname,
SUM(subtotal_invoiced) AS Total
FROM sales_flat_order AS a
GROUP BY customer_email
ORDER BY SUM(subtotal_invoiced) DESC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    customer_email, customer_firstname, customer_lastname,
    SUM(subtotal_invoiced) AS total_of_orders,
    MIN(created_at) as first_order_date,
    COUNT(*) as num_of_orders
FROM sales_flat_order
GROUP BY customer_email
```

Comment: I get the following error when I do this:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MIN(created_at) as first_order_date, COUNT (*) as num_of_ord

Comment: Please add comma after `total_of_orders`.  Have edited the answer.

Comment: I still get a similar error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) as num_of_orders FROM sales_flat_order GROUP BY customer_emai

Comment: removed the space before (, so now it count(*).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    customer_email,
    customer_firstname,
    customer_lastname,
    count(customer_email) as num_of_orders,
    created_at,
    SUM(subtotal_invoiced) AS Total
FROM
    sales_flat_order AS a
GROUP BY customer_email
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Should always work since create_at is in chronological order, but if you having issue use min().

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    customer_email,
    customer_firstname,
    customer_lastname,
    count(customer_email) as num_of_order,
    min(created_at) first_order,
    SUM(subtotal_invoiced) AS Total
FROM
    sales_flat_order AS a
GROUP BY customer_email
ORDER BY first_order ASC
```

Comment: Why should we use `distinct` ? Seems redundant as we use group by `customer_email`  Sorting is slow don the query and should be probably committed if not necessary.